# Spring, AspectJ: injection for deserialized objects

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, deserialization, autowired

I need to put some object into ActiveMQ and then deserialize it. This object contain transient field which should be initialized upon deserialization. According to this doc (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) it should work automatically in the Spring, but it doesn't. CloudBean is always null after the deserialization.

Here are my classes:

```
package core.utilities.handlers;

//imports...

@Component
@Configurable
public class InitialCopyHandler implements JobHandler  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2617677940515776720L;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(InitialCopyHandler.class);
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Autowired private transient CloudBean cloudBean;

    public InitialCopyHandler() {
    }

    public InitialCopyHandler( String username, String password ) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle() {
        try {
            logger.info("Copy from default to " + username);
            String webCloudDataDir = cloudBean.getWebCloudDataDir();
            Sardine defaultSardine = cloudBean.getDefaultSardine();
            InputStream is = defaultSardine.get(webCloudDataDir + FILE_COUNTRIES_LIST);
            cloudBean.getUserSardine(username,password).put(webCloudDataDir + FILE_COUNTRIES_LIST, is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

CloudBean.java:

```
package core.domain.cloud;

//imports...

@Component
public class CloudBean {
    protected Sardine defaultSardine;
    protected Sardine userSardine;
    protected String webCloudDataDir;
    protected String webCloud;
    protected static String defaultCar;
    protected static String defaultCarPassword;
    protected HttpHeaders headers;

    @Autowired private ConfigurationFactory configuration;

    public CloudBean() {
    }

 // init block
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        webCloudDataDir = configuration.getConfigurationValue(DEFAULT_CLOUD_WEBDAV_LOCATION) + DIR_CLOUD_DATA;
        webCloud = configuration.getConfigurationValue(DEFAULT_CLOUD_LOCATION);
        defaultCar = configuration.getConfigurationValue(DEFAULT_CLOUD_ACCOUNT);
        defaultCarPassword = configuration.getConfigurationValue(DEFAULT_CLOUD_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD);
        defaultSardine = SardineFactory.begin(defaultCar, defaultCarPassword);
        defaultSardine.enableCompression();

        headers = HttpUtilities.initHeaders(defaultCar,defaultCarPassword);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes Sardine for the particular user
     * @param username
     * @param password
     * @return Sardine
     */
    public Sardine getUserSardine( String username, String password ) {
        userSardine = SardineFactory.begin(username,password);
        userSardine.enableCompression();
        return userSardine;
    }

    public Sardine getDefaultSardine() {
        return defaultSardine;
    }

    public String getWebCloudDataDir() {
        return webCloudDataDir;
    }
}
```

Excerpt from the Consumer.java (deserialization part):

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    if( message instanceof ObjectMessage ) {
        ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage)message;
        try {
            JobHandler msg = (JobHandler)objectMessage.getObject();
            es.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    msg.handle();
                }
            });
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Since you haven't included it in your question you may miss some Spring configuration as required in 7.8.1 of the documentation you linked to. So you may forgot to configure weaving with AspectJ ('<context:spring-configured/>') or did not configure the 'AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect' or you may missed the dependency to spring-aspects.jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code Spring is just not involved in the deserialization, so it cannot inject any dependencies.

In the linked spring documentation the pojos are created by a spring factory. You cannot use that approach because you create your instances by deserialization.

What you can do :

In your Consumer class get a bean factory injected :

```
@Autowired    
AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;
```

after deserializing the object autowire it :

```
 JobHandler msg = (JobHandler)objectMessage.getObject();
 beanFactory.autowireBean(msg);
```

thats all.